# Efficient way to get only _ids in ElasticSearch - Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is this the most efficient way to retrieve only ids from ElasticSearch?

```
requestBuilder.setQuery(queryBuilder);
    requestBuilder.setFrom(start);
    requestBuilder.setSize(limit);
    requestBuilder.setFetchSource(false);

    SearchResponse response = requestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

    SearchHit[] hits = response.getHits().getHits();
    List<Long> refugeeIds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SearchHit hit : hits) {
        if (hit.getId() != null) {
            refugeeIds.add(Long.parseLong(hit.getId().toString()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be the best way. You don't return the `_source` and ES will only return the `_type`, `_index`, `_score` and `_id`.